# Docker and Rails: unable to access log file

Tags: ruby-on-rails, docker, permissions

When I start my Rails development server (or run a test) I get the following error:

> Rails Error: Unable to access log file. Please ensure that
> /usr/src/app/log/development.log exists and is writable (ie, make it
> writable for user and group: chmod 0664
> /usr/src/app/log/development.log). The log level has been raised to
> WARN and the output directed to STDERR until the problem is fixed.

This problem persists even after I do `chmod -R 777 log`.

I have my app Dockerized running Alpine Linux.

What could be the cause of this issue?

Comment: Is your `log` folder shared on your `volumes`? (I suppose you're using docker-compose)

Comment: It is, and it turned out that was the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out the problem was because my `log` directory was mounted as the PostgreSQL log directory.

```
services:
  postgres:
    image: postgres:12.3-alpine
    mem_limit: 64m
    volumes:
      - ./log:/root/log:cached # <-- this line was the culprit
      - postgresql:/var/lib/postgresql/data:delegated
    ports:
      - "127.0.0.1:5432:5432"
    environment:
      PSQL_HISTFILE: /root/log/.psql_history
      POSTGRES_USER: postgres
      POSTGRES_PASSWORD: postgres
    restart: on-failure
    healthcheck:
      test: ["CMD-SHELL", "pg_isready -U postgres"]
      interval: 10s
      timeout: 2s
      retries: 10
    logging:
      driver: none
```

I describe the problem in more detail in [this GitHub issue](https://github.com/Ruby-Starter-Kits/Docker-Rails-Generator/issues/49).